# Можно ли заполнить гугл таблицы используя редактор скриптов?

Tags: google-apps-script

Я выполняю код в редакторе скриптов, получается вот так [image: .]

Получается хорошо, но мне нужно что бы получалось вот так вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли как то получить такой же результат? Возможно ли  в больших количествах? Что бы все данные вводились сразу большой кучей в столбик?

Вот мой код:

```js
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */
function myFunction() {
  var name1 = new Array(); // Объявление массива name и занесение в него большого количества имён
  // Список имен
  var RandElement1 = name1[Math.floor(Math.random() * name1.length)]; // Выбор случайного элемента из массива
  //message.channel.send(RandElement) // Отправка сообщения со случайным элементом из массива в чат

  var name2 = new Array(); // Объявление массива name и занесение в него большого количества имён
  // Список фамилий
  var RandElement2 = name2[Math.floor(Math.random() * name2.length)]; // Выбор случайного элемента из массива
  //message.channel.send(RandElement) // Отправка сообщения со случайным элементом из массива в чат

  var name5 = new Array(`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`);
  var RandElement5 = name5[Math.floor(Math.random() * name5.length)];

  var name6 = new Array(`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`);
  var RandElement6 = name6[Math.floor(Math.random() * name6.length)];

  var name7 = new Array(`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`);
  var RandElement7 = name7[Math.floor(Math.random() * name7.length)];

  function textTransform(text) {
    var arrru = [
      // Список символов для подстановок
    ];
    var arren = [
      // Список символов транслита
    ];

    var reg = new RegExp('[^' + arrru.join('') + 'a-zA-Z]', 'g');

    text = text.replace(reg, '');

    for (var i = 0; i < arrru.length; i++) {
      var reg = new RegExp(arrru[i], 'g');
      text = text.replace(reg, arren[i]);
    }

    return text;
  }

  console.log(
    RandElement1 +
      ` ` +
      RandElement2 +
      ` ` +
      textTransform(RandElement1 + RandElement2) +
      RandElement5 +
      RandElement6 +
      ` ` +
      textTransform(RandElement2) +
      RandElement6 +
      RandElement5 +
      RandElement7
  );
}
```

Полный листинг программы тут https://gist.github.com/contributorpw/8bba4a316492acd1991adcc19f778147

Comment: Решился вопрос?

Comment: Не-а, не решился

Comment: Я отформатирую ваш код и приведу рабочий пример.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала выведите часть код в отдельные файлы проекта

Получает на вход книгу, списки для генерации и количество генераций. По умолчанию использует текущую книгу. Если не передаются списки генерации, то в книге должны быть листы `name1`, `name2`.

dataGenerator.js

```js
function generateData_(
  book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
  names1 = [],
  names2 = [],
  count = 1
) {
  const name1 = names1.length
    ? names1
    : book
        .getRange('name1!A:A')
        .getValues()
        .map((row) => row[0])
        .filter((item) => item !== '');

  const name2 = names2.length
    ? names2
    : book
        .getRange('name2!A:A')
        .getValues()
        .map((row) => row[0])
        .filter((item) => item !== '');

  const name5 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  const name6 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  const name7 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

  const data = [];

  while (count > 0) {
    const randElement1 = name1[Math.floor(Math.random() * name1.length)];
    const randElement2 = name2[Math.floor(Math.random() * name2.length)];
    const randElement5 = name5[Math.floor(Math.random() * name5.length)];

    const randElement6 = name6[Math.floor(Math.random() * name6.length)];

    const RandElement7 = name7[Math.floor(Math.random() * name7.length)];

    data.push([
      `${randElement1} ${randElement2}`,
      textTransform_(randElement1 + randElement2) + randElement5 + randElement6,
      textTransform_(randElement2) + randElement6 + randElement5 + RandElement7,
    ]);
    count--;
  }
  return data;
}
```

#### Как применять `generateData_`

Генерирует 100 записей в текущей книге

```js
const data1 = generateData_(undefined, undefined, undefined, 100);
```

Генерирует 10 записей в переданной книге

```js
const data1 = generateData_(book, undefined, undefined, 100);
```

Генерирует 1 запись в переданной книге на основе заданных массивов

```js
const data2 = generateData_(book, ['Имя1', 'Имя2'], ['Фамиль1', 'Фамиль2']);
```

#### Применяем и вставляем данные в Таблицу

Берет активную книгу и генерирует новые записи на листе `Data`.

userAction.js

```js
function userActionRun() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Генерирует 10 записей
  const data1 = generateData_(book, undefined, undefined, 100);

  // Генерирует 1 запись из переданных массивов
  const data2 = generateData_(book, ['Имя1', 'Имя2'], ['Фамиль1', 'Фамиль2']);

  const data = [...data1, ...data2];

  if (data.length) {
    const sheetData = book.getSheetByName('Data');
    if (sheetData.getLastRow() === sheetData.getMaxRows())
      sheetData.insertRowAfter(sheetData.getLastRow());

    sheetData
      .getRange(sheetData.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
      .setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Функцию `textTransform_` я менять не стал, но там есть что поправить.

Результат работы программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BBObMiYI1TUU2CvQZPXhnX7hXfx8Xyqv1n8dDt9mogw/edit?usp=sharing